# Can I include a file of strings that would be autocompleting and crossplatform (iOS/Android)?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I'm not even sure what the vocabulary for this question is, but I'd like to have a file which is a list of strings which could be included as constants in Android and iOS.

I'm trying to find better vocab to describe this issue so comments are greatly appreciated too, thanks all.

Edit: For example, I'd like to have a file such as

color_names.txt

```
COLOR_NAME_BLUE  "blue"
COLOR_NAME_RED   "red"
COLOR_NAME_GREEN "green"
```

Which I can include in both an Android and an iOS project I have, in a way that in the code COLOR_NAME_BLUE is symbol checked, and if someone were to type COLOR_NAME_BLEU it would throw a compile error.

The actual file will be much larger and is something I want to be maintainable.  I could put this in JSON but then I'd have to do the checking at run time, which isn't terrible I just am trying to figure out if there is a better way.

Comment: To use in your app? Or while programming? If programming, in iOS just #define them.

Comment: @RoboticCat these are to use while programming.  I don't want to just create a long #define in iOS because then I'd have to maintain two copies of this (one for android and one for iOS)

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also have iOS and Android apps that should be sharing strings.

You should use a python program (or some inferior scripting system) that takes your input file (checking it for errors) and outputs a Localizable.strings file for the iOS and strings.xml file for the Android.

So long as you have a good handle on your directory structure, you should be able to place both the Localizable.strings file and strings.xml file right where they need to be for your build.

For example, for a label pair like this:

```
PRIMARY_AGE_10 "Primary Age 10"
```

The label/string matchup is pretty obvious for the Android strings.xml:

```
<string name="PRIMARY_AGE_10">Primary Age 10</string>
```

The iOS Localizable.strings format is like this:

```
"PRIMARY_AGE_10" = "Primary Age 10";
```

Then when I want to use the label "Primary Age 10" instead of using an NSString, or  @"Primary Age 10" i just make a call like this:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"PRIMARY_AGE_10", nil)
```

One other big advantage is if you need to localize, you can generate multiple Localizable.strings files and strings.xml files.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best answer I've seen yet.